# merging files in r without merge()

Tags: r, merge

I have two files I would like to merge. I would like to merge them so that the second and third column incorporate both files start and stop locations for each of the 22 chromosomes and find the corresponding Cn (the eighth column) result for that file.

**file 1**

```
Chromosome  Start   End lengthMB    probes  snps    imba    log2    Cn  mCn
chr1    0   121184898   121.185 11403   3272    0.263868683 -0.03922829 2   1
chr1    144028314   147376741   3.348   392 55  0.666732903 0.149629608 4   0
chr1    147376741   149815307   2.439   45  1   NA  0.081578404 3   0
chr1    149815307   152973261   3.158   355 98  NA  0.175954714 4   0
chr1    152973261   153223301   0.25    32  1   NA  0.250464238 5   0
chr1    153223301   164587468   11.364  910 270 NA  0.169542015 4   0
chr1    164587468   164680884   0.093   11  7   NA  0.110598177 3   0
chr1    164680884   167797512   3.117   265 82  0.619468523 0.178797081 4   0
chr1    167797512   168022812   0.225   10  1   NA  0.262534983 5   0
```

**file 2**

```
Chromosome  Start   End lengthMB    probes  snps    imba    log2    Cn  mCn
chr1    0   121184898   121.185 11405   3273    0.267231258 -0.040215328    2   1
chr1    144028314   147376741   3.348   393 55  0.649314008 0.156409264 4   0
chr1    147376741   149573557   2.197   44  1   NA  0.118886434 4   0
chr1    149573557   158729529   9.156   837 221 NA  0.193681628 4   0
chr1    158729529   158809353   0.08    13  1   NA  0.031239059 4   0
chr1    158809353   164628199   5.819   451 141 0.610374455 0.182849884 4   0
chr1    164628199   164836103   0.208   25  12  NA  0.253876895 4   0
chr1    164836103   165418619   0.583   61  16  NA  0.186622113 4   0
```

**Output**

```
Chromosome  Start   End Cn_File_1   mCn_File_1  Cn_File_2   mCn_File_2
chr1    0   121184898   2   1   2   0
chr1    144028314   147376741   4   0   4   0
chr1    147376741   149573557   3   0   4   0
chr1    149573557   149815307   3   0   4   0
chr1    149815307   152973261   4   0   4   0
chr1    152973261   153223301   5   0   4   0
chr1    153223301   158729529   4   0   4   0
chr1    158729529   158809353   4   0   4   0
chr1    158809353   164587468   4   0   4   0
chr1    164587468   164628199   3   0   4   0
chr1    164628199   164680884   3   0   4   0
chr1    164680884   164836103   4   0   4   0
chr1    164836103   165418619   4   0   4   0
```

So far I am looping through all the chromosomes to find the right start and stop values for the corresponding chromosome in both files. Then I put together the starts and stops from both, but I am not sure how to then find the right Cn value (on the eighth column of each file).

```
for (i in 1:22) {
    start1 <- file1$Chromosome == paste(chromosome,i, sep="")
    start2 <- file2$Chromosome == paste(chromosome,i, sep="")
    both_starts <- unique(sort(c(file1$Start[start1], file2$Start[start2])))
    both_starts <- unique(both_starts)
    both_stops <- unique(sort(c(file1$End[start1], file2$End[start2])))
    both_stops <- unique(both_stops)
    start <- append(start, both_starts)
    stop <- append(stop, both_stops)
    chr <- append(chr, rep(paste(chromosome, i, sep=""), length(both_starts)))
        for (i in length(both_starts)) {
            print(file1$Start[start1][i])
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why without `merge`?

Comment: You can use `match` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possibility using the `survSplit` function from package `survival` and then still using `merge`.

```
lst1 <- split(d1, d1$Chromosome)
lst2 <- split(d2, d2$Chromosome)
require(survival)
# merge
do.call(rbind, mapply(FUN = function(x, y) 
{
  x$event <- y$event <- 0
  d1.spl <- survSplit(x, cut=y$End, start='Start', end='End', event='event')
  d2.spl <- survSplit(y, cut=x$End, start='Start', end='End', event='event')
  mrg <- merge(d1.spl, d2.spl, 
               by=c('Chromosome', 'Start', 'End'), 
               #all=TRUE, 
               suffixes = c("_File_1","_File_2"))
  mrg[c('Chromosome', 'Start', 'End', 'Cn_File_1', 'mCn_File_1', 'Cn_File_2', 'mCn_File_2')]
},
lst1, lst2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))


##          Chromosome     Start       End Cn_File_1 mCn_File_1 Cn_File_2 mCn_File_2
##  chr1.1        chr1         0 121184898         2          1         2          1
##  chr1.2        chr1 144028314 147376741         4          0         4          0
##  chr1.3        chr1 147376741 149573557         3          0         4          0
##  chr1.4        chr1 149573557 149815307         3          0         4          0
##  chr1.5        chr1 149815307 152973261         4          0         4          0
##  chr1.6        chr1 152973261 153223301         5          0         4          0
##  chr1.7        chr1 153223301 158729529         4          0         4          0
##  chr1.8        chr1 158729529 158809353         4          0         4          0
##  chr1.9        chr1 158809353 164587468         4          0         4          0
##  chr1.10       chr1 164587468 164628199         3          0         4          0
##  chr1.11       chr1 164628199 164680884         3          0         4          0
##  chr1.12       chr1 164680884 164836103         4          0         4          0
##  chr1.13       chr1 164836103 165418619         4          0         4          0
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, just need to rename the columns.  This way you can extract whichever other columns you may wish:

```
file_merged <- merge(file1, file2, by.x = c("Chromosome", "Start", "End"), by.y = c("Chromosome", "Start", "End")) 
file_merged[,colnames(file_merged) %in% c("Chromosome", "Start", "End", "Cn.x", "mCn.x", "Cn.y", "mCn.y")]

  Chromosome     Start       End Cn.x mCn.x Cn.y mCn.y
1       chr1         0 121184898    2     1    2     1
2       chr1 144028314 147376741    4     0    4     0
3       chr1 147376741 149815307    3     0    4     0
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using the `reshape2` package for anything after loading it.

Comment: @ping, my mistake, that was for something else on my page that I didn't mean to copy.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: So for this to work, I first split the files based on chromosomes? Otherwise it takes all the starts and stops to come from the same chromosome?

Comment: @user3324491 Couldn't you just add in "Chromosome" to the filter?